# Can't use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar with android.useAndroidX=true

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-appcompat, androidx

in app/build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

in my activity I use

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

Nice. It's work finde.

But when I migrate to `androidx` I add this:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

As result now my activity not compile with error:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

Cannot resolve symbol 'v7'
```

Is it possible to use `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` together with `anrdoidx.*` package?

Answer (score 36):

Since you are migrating your project to **androidx**

1. With Android Studio 3.2 and higher, you can migrate an existing 
   project to AndroidX by selecting **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** from 
   the menu bar.
2. Remove imports having **v7** support and import **androidx** dependencies all over in your project.
3. Add implementation **'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'** in your 
   app gradle( if not added already).
4. Import **androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar** in class and replace `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>` with `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar/>` in XML layout.

**Answering your second query** : you cannot use both v7 support library and androidx in same project as androidx is full replacement of the Support Library provided in Android Jetpack.

Also update your project to use the final version of the support library: **version 28.0.0** (highly recommended).

For further details about androidx migration visit this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 8):

Use the updated component `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` and remove all `android.support.v7.*` packages.