# Not able to use CoordinatorLayout in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-coordinatorlayout

My problem is that I am not able to use CoordinatorLayout in Android Studio despite adding all the possible dependencies in my build.gradle file. The class is not instantinated.
Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.uiuxpractical4materialdesign"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/coordinatorlayout/R$attr
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:211)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:403)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:186)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:144)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:309)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:418)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:429)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:333)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:323)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:394)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:200)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:572)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$5(RenderTask.java:698)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Due to this, the class is not instantinated and I get something like this:-
[image: The CoordinatorLayout]
Also, here a small picture of the error too:-
[image: The Error]
Thanks for everyone helping out there to solve this issue.
Please also inform if you need anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add this line in your dependencies in **build.gradle**

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.2'
```

don't worry about the difference between com.android..... and androidx.... This implementation androidx. automatically migrate the implementation if your android studio is higher than 3.2.

you can check this link.https://stackoverflow.com/a/58619780/10075771 it will help you understand also the situation :)
Hoping i help you in little way :)

Comment: Ok.Thanks. I would try that also.

Comment: Thanks so much @NoName, for helping me out there.

Comment: I added those lines and tried the support Coordinator Layout . But it didn't work.

Comment: But later, when I migrated the project to androidx and used the androidx (jetpack) coordinator Layout, it was instatinated successfully. Once, again thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

try adding below dependencies 
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I should try using the support library instead of the androidx one ?

Comment: Thanks again.But I am sorry to say that this doesn't work.

Comment: Below three dependencies are required for constraintlayout:- 
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$app_compat_version"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$app_compat_version"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraint_version"
Please verify the same.

Comment: But my probelem appears to be some strange one because I had added all these. Whatsoever, it is now solved, you can see the accepted answer.